# を降りる or から降りる ? Which one is correct

Tags: particle-を, particle-から

For example which one is more correct?

- 彼は車から降りた。
- 彼は車を降りた。

Which version is the proper, textbook style Japanese?  Which one is the more common, everyday Japanese?
Please explain why! Thanks !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the following article cited in [this chiebukuro answer](https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q11119950306).

- 杉村泰, [起点を示す格助詞「を」と「から」の使い分け](https://nagoya.repo.nii.ac.jp/records/6472)

---

The following sentences are more natural with を.

- 毎朝7時に家**を**出る
- 大学**を**出てまっすぐ家に帰った
- 母は4時にデパート**を**出た

The following sentences are more natural with から.

- 夫が知らない女の家**から**出てきたのをみた
- 犯人は裏口**から**出てきた
- 地震で崩れたビル**から**出た

The difference is:

- In sentences natural with を, the focus is on 'completing the purpose and leave the place'
- In those natural with から, the focus is more on 'moving from one place to another'.

In line with this difference, 車から降りる is used when you mean just getting off a car as a physical object where as 車を降りる is more natural when getting off the car as a transportation, after arriving the destination ('completing the purpose of using a car').

Because the word 'car' is often meant as a transportation, to some extent 車を降りる is more common although 車から降りる is perfectly correct.

Answer (score 0):

Both are correct, there is no difference in nuance. And both are commonly used.

But, in my opinion, 車から降りる means "getting out of the car in order to go somewhere". On the other hand, 車を降りる means "arriving the destination and getting out of the car".

Comment: IMO, if I were outside the train observing them, I'd use either.  But if I were inside the train observing them, I'd only use を.  から somehow feels wrong in that scenario.

Comment: I didn't realize it, but it certainly is. In my image, を seems to suddenly change from being in the car to being outside the car. から feels like the process of moving from inside the car to outside the car.

Comment: I feel that one would never bother to give an object if using を, since presumably it's pretty clear what you're riding when you might say 降りる.